# Diabo 3 vs Diablo 3 Reaper of souls

Tags: diablo-iii, ps3

Hi I am planing on buying Diablo 3 or Diablo 3 Reaper of souls on PS3. I have never played either of them. I will most probably only buy one of them.

So my question  is if I only buy 1 which would you suggest I buy for the best gaming experience. For example if I only buy the expansion will I still play the original story line and if I don't will the story still make sense if I miss the events in the original?

Comment: The Evil Edition will have both D3 and Reaper of Souls; probably something that will factor into your decision.

Comment: You can't have Reaper of souls alone, it's not a standalone game.

Comment: You can likely avoid those downvotes if you did a quick google search before asking the question.  You would have learned that Reaper of Souls is an expansion of Diablo 3 and then likely learned what that meant.

Comment: People voting to close as "something that is not possible" should note that the rerelease box art for Diablo 3 titles it "Diablo 3 reaper of souls". a close vote is not a super down vote for lack of research -- please don't use it as one.

Answer (score 2):

The expansion is not available separately for consoles, when you see "Reaper of Souls" for PS3 it is the Ultimate Evil Edition.

Aside from the inclusion of the expansion content (including a new campaign chapter, a new character class, and adventure mode) this edition also has a different system for managing enemy difficulty -- where enemies will be of a similar level to yourself that is different from the original edition where you need to complete the campaign several times at least to reach max level.

In my opinion, the new system is better.

Given the trivial price difference in most places I can see, I would recommend you go for the newer version. The original version doesn't have anything in it that the new one lacks, and it adds quite a lot of new content.